# Erro ao usar SQL com javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Gostaria de saber o que está de errado com essas linhas, especialmente na query, pois não está a funcionar:

```
pool.query('SELECT * FROM `info` WHERE `id` = 1', function(err, row1) {
    var jogo = row1[0].jogo;
    var numerojogadores = row1[0].numerojogadores;
    // Se o numero de jogadores for 2 ou mais começa...
    if (numerojogadores > 1) {
        // Inicio do Contador
        socket.broadcast.emit('count', count);
        count--;
        console.log(count);
        // Fim do Contador
    }
    if (count === 0) {
        var novojogo = "jogo2";
        pool.query('UPDATE info SET jogo = novojogo WHERE id = 1', function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            count = 60;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Qual é o erro que te dá?

Comment: Unknow column '1'

Comment: Esse erro näo será de outra query? Testa correr esse UPDATE diretamente no mysql, dá o mesmo erro?

Comment: `'UPDATE info SET jogo = novojogo WHERE id = 1'`?

Comment: Diretamente no mysql funciona, vou deixar o meu codigo todo.

Comment: Coloquei o codigo todo.

Comment: Se substituir a var por um numero, já funciona. Alguém sabe alguma forma de se colocar vars?

Comment: Cara eu acho que esse problema está relacionado aos backticks que você colocou. Qual é a linha que dá o erro?

Comment: Eu já percebi, teria que colocar desta forma: '+var+'